# Alignment glitch on privileges pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When you open the privileges page and select a privilege with a long name, the percentage of the *next* privilege is aligned incorrectly.  This happens for example when you [choose “cast close and reopen votes” privilege](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions).

Always reproducible with Firefox 3.6.12, Internet Explorer 8.0.7600.16385 and Chrome 8.0.552.215 on Windows 7.

My guess is that the problem itself had been always there, but the font used during the beta was not wide enough to trigger this glitch whereas the font used in the new design is wide enough to trigger it.

[*Added*: Another cause seems to be that the font used to show the percentage is (probably) higher than the vertical space between rows.  Actually, this table is constructed by using floats instead of using a simple <table> element and, if I understand the intent correctly, the very reason for this is to handle the horizontal overflow nicely.  The font being higher than the vertical space destroys this gimmick and produces a worse result when the horizontal overflow occurs.]

Screenshot of [the page about the “cast close and reopen votes” privilege](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) with Firefox 3.6.12:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: in Chrome 7 + Win XP too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Haha, nice fix! :)  Verified.

Comment: you're correct about the font size issue. I can't really make the sidebar wider, or shrink the font. so I think a highlighted background color is the best way to go. I'll need to check this on the other sites, may apply the same type of fix.